# I rendered my animation, but I can only save the last frame as a png

Tags: animation

This is my second blender creation, and I tried animating it which went well. I clicked "Render animation" without changing any render settings, and then spent the next 10 hours rendering this 90 frame animation. I now cannot find any other frames as images, and can only save the last frame as a file. Please help me figure out what to do, as I don't really feel like spending another day rendering.

Comment: Which directory have you set as output path in the _Output Properties_? If you didn't tell Blender a specific path, the images are usually saved in C:\tmp but beware: by default, the _Overwrite_ option is enabled. So always rendering in the tmp folder will only keep the last rendered images.

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add that link in the question.  Could be a simple render setting.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know it saved anywhere Thanks for the solve!

Comment: @RickT Uploading an example blend file to see the output path is a waste of disk space.